# Python - Delete directory which contains actual Python Script

Tags: python, file, directory

How do I delete the directory which contains the executed python file?

Comment: Write a DLL that kills your Python process and deletes the folder, then inject it into explorer.exe ;)

Comment: and why? sounds like a pretty stupid idea

Comment: the same way you delete any directory, only the operating system won't let you because it will have a lock on the file.

Comment: because i have a automtic script which installs software on a pc with log in data. i dont want to let the data on the pc.

Comment: If you're looking for the path to delete `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` gives you the directory of the executed python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No program can delete itself or the folder it's in while it's still running. The OS will prevent this from happening, independently of whether you use Python or C or any other language.

You have two options:

- Have your Python script put the log file into a subdirectory, and delete that at the end of your script's run (but of course that fails when the user Ctrl-Cs out of your script.
- Run another script after the first one (in a different directory) that removes the directory of the first script. Of course, again, you're not safe against user intervention. And of course, you'll have the second script left over at the end...

Why does your program store passwords on the hard drive of the system it runs on anyway?

Comment: Im not speaking on behalf of the OP, but I know for one of my former jobs, we were storing sensitive information "on-the-fly" on PC's around the US (it was certification testing and testing centers).  I can see the OP's question potentially being linked to malware development, but in our case we had legit cause to download data, run information, and do our best to remove it all from the PC after each run.  With that said, I agree with your two solutions as we ended up doing the latter of the two you suggested.  Just food for thought.

Comment: @Nascent_Notes: Oh! Of course, I didn't even think about the possibility that the OP might be using this for malware development.

Comment: @Nascent_Notes & Tim Should we forbid or suppress everything only because it could be used fpr malware development?

Comment: @glglgl, I think my comment was taken poorly by Tim.  I wasn't saying one way or the other whether it should or shouldn't be commented on.  Rather, my only intent was to provide a possible reason why someone would want to do this which comes in response to "Why does your program store passwords on the hard drive of the system it runs on anyway?".